# YAML Json over multiple lines

Tags: json, yaml

Let's look at the following YAML definition:

```
#yaml
---
user1:
    name: "User name"
    age: "adf"
    address:
        street: "some street"
        no: "23"
        postcode: "2341234"

user2: {name: "User name", age: "adf", address: { street: "some street", no: "23",  postcode: "2341234"}}
```

The **user1** and **user2** definitions are identical. 
I do prefer the user2 style sometimes, but when the definition becomes too long it's getting a problem to put everything in one line.

**Is there a way of mixing JSON style on a multiline level?**
Something like:

```
user3: {name: "User name", age: "adf",
            address: { street: "some street", no: "23",  postcode: "2341234"}
       }
```

Comment: Is there an answer to this question?

Comment: No, I haven't found a way to do this. Imo, it's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, there is, but your programming language or parser implementation might not support this syntax.

---

Actually, **you can do this, though** I believe **this line is not** supposed to be **well formatted one**. **It depends on what parser / programming language you use** and whether the rules of it are strict or flexible.

According to [YAML flow styles](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#style/flow/), [YAML flow mappings](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2790832) and [YAML docs, Example 2.6. Mapping of Mappings](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963):

```
Mark McGwire: {hr: 65, avg: 0.278}
Sammy Sosa: {
  hr: 63,
  avg: 0.288
}
```

So as to verify I's possible I've just put this YAML (I left this code not properly formatted to be absolutely sure):

```
---
user1:
    name: "User name"
    age: "adf"
    address:
        street: "some street"
    no: "23"
    postcode: "2341234"

user2: {name: "User name", age: "adf", address: { street: "some street", no: "23",  postcode: "2341234"}}

user3: {name: "User name", age: "adf",
        address: { street: "some street", no: "23",  postcode: "2341234"}
    }
```

...to several online YAML validators.

Several of them validated is successfully:

- http://www.yamllint.com/ - ok
- http://nodeca.github.io/js-yaml/ - ok
- http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ - ok

And the next one didn't:

- http://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator - malformed line

Also Ruby language (I haven't checked it via Perl, might be some of these online validators did this for me) allows this notation. Remember, that **your programming language / parser might be syntax sensitive therefore this code will be wrong**.

Personally, I wouldn't mix up different styles. The best way to my mind would be converting some lines to *flow* style, and some of them to *plain*:

```
user3:
    name: "User name",
    age: "adf",
    address: { street: "some street", no: "23",  postcode: "2341234" }
```